# Kotlin View Binding java.lang.IllegalStateException: view must not be null inside listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using [View Binding](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) from Kotlin Android Extensions:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_user_profile.*
```

I want to display a value from Cloud Firestore in a **fragment**:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("users")
    .document("1")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
        my_text_view.text = doc["name"] as String
    }
```

It works if the fragment is still shown when data is received. But if user close the fragment (pressing back) *before* data is received, it crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: my_text_view must not be null
```

How do I avoid this?

---

Of course I can use `my_text_view?.text = ...` but

- Someday I can forget to put `?`
- It doesn't solve the problem that the listener stays alive after the fragment is destroyed

I think I want something like [`addOnSuccessListener(Activity, OnSuccessListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnSuccessListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)) but for Fragment instead Activity

Comment: `my_text_view` is an extension property created automatically by Kotlin View Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your callback if the fragment is still added to its host activity,

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
.collection("users")
.document("1")
.get()
.addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
    if (isAdded) {
        my_text_view.text = doc["name"] as String
    }
}
```

However, a better solution would be to move your business logic to a viewmodel.

Comment: It seems to me that `if (isAdded)` is by fact same as `my_text_view` null-checking (see my question edit)

Comment: If I move business logic to a viewmodel, should I unsubscribe the listener when fragment is closed?

Comment: If you use a ViewModel then you can listen to the viewmodel's data using LiveData, which handles the fragment lifecycle automatically, so you do not have to worry about subscribe/unsubscribe, happens automatically.