# How to add an Fragment-scoped listener for Task?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments

[`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) used in Firebase has method [`addOnSuccessListener(Activity, OnSuccessListener)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnSuccessListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)). The listener added using this method is automatically removed during activity's `onStop()`.

What is the nearest equivalent for **fragment**? I.e. I want to add a listener inside a fragment but don't keep it after the fragment is closed.

Comment: The reason why I need it is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53510119/6131611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LiveData & ViewModel:

1. create ViewModel & "Success Event" LiveData in ViewModel
2. observer that liveData from your fragment
3. when receiving OnSuccessListener() -> update the above LiveData content